# Toward a cyclotomic Riemann hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, riemann-hypothesis, cyclotomic-fields

For an integer $n \ge 3$, consider the function $$u(n) = \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n}$$ with $\sigma$ the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). Now consider the sequence (bounded below and decreasing) $$v_n = \sup_{m>n} u(m).$$

Then [Robin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Robin%27s_theorem) states that the Riemann hypothesis (RH) is true if and only if the sequence $(v_n)$ reaches its limit (which means the existence of $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $v_m = \lim_{n \to \infty} v_n$).

---

To illustrate the complexity of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r]$ of cyclotomic integers of degree $r$ (with $\zeta_r=e^{2i\pi/r}$), here is the picture of the set $$\{\sum_{i=0}^4 a_i\zeta_5^i \ | \ a_i \in \mathbb{Z}, |a_i| \le 3 \} \subset \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5].$$
[image]

---

Consider the quotient map $$i: \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r]/\sim$$ with $x \sim y$ if and only if there is a unit $u \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r]$ such that $x=uy$. Then consider $$\mathcal{P}_r = i(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R}),$$ where $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R}$ is the ring of real cyclotomic integers of degree $r$.

For $x \in \mathcal{P}_r$, and $a \in i^{-1}(\{ x\})$, consider the set of divisors $$D(x)= i(\{ b \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R} \ | \  a/b \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R} \}).$$

**Question 1**: Is the set $D(x)$ finite (for $x$ nonzero)?

As pointed out by Wojowu in comment (before revision), the group of units can be huge, and so without quotient, the set of divisors could be infinite (for example, let $\phi$ be the golden ratio, then $\phi^k, \phi^{-k} \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$, and $1 = \phi^k \cdot \phi^{-k}$ for all $k$). Then Question 1 asks whether the quotient is sufficient to make the set finite.

**Answer to Question 1** (*after the comments of François Brunault*): Yes.
*Proof*: the ring of algebraic integers in a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a [Dedekind domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain). So any nonzero proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R}$ decomposes uniquely (up to permutation) into a product of (finitely many) prime ideals. Then a nonzero ideal admits only finitely many dividing ideals. But $$x \sim y \Leftrightarrow x(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R}) = y(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R}),$$ so the set $D(x)$ is in bijection with the set of singly generated dividing ideals of $x(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R})$. $\square$

---

To define a divisor function $\sigma$, we first need to define a natural non-negative representative for each element of $\mathcal{P}_r$, by a map
$$\tau: \mathcal{P}_r  \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}.$$ For so, first consider the surjective map: $$ s: \mathbb{Z}^{r} \to  \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r]$$ such that $s(n_0,n_1, \dots, n_{r-1}) = \sum_i n_i \zeta_r^i$.

Let $P(\mathbb{Z}^{r})$ be the set of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^{r}$. Consider the minimizers map $$m: P(\mathbb{Z}^{r}) \to P(\mathbb{Z}^{r})$$
such that $$m(S) = \{ v \in S \ | \  \Vert v \Vert_2 \le \Vert w \Vert_2, \ \forall w \in S \},$$
next consider the lexicographical order on $\mathbb{Z}^{r}$ defined by $$(n_0, n_1, \dots, n_{r-1}) \le (n'_0, n'_1, \dots, n'_{r-1}) \Leftrightarrow $$ $$n_{r-1} < n'_{r-1} \text{ or } (n_{r-1} = n'_{r-1} \text{ and } n_{r-2} < n'_{r-2}) \text{ or } \dots$$  Finally consider the *lexicographical first* map $l: P(\mathbb{Z}^{r}) \to \mathbb{Z}^{r}$ such that $l(S) = min(S,\le)$.

Now we can defined the teased map $\tau: \mathcal{P}_r \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ as follows: $$ \tau(x) = s \circ l \circ m \circ s^{-1} (i^{-1} (\{x \})\cap \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}).$$

Note that $\tau$ is unital, i.e. for every unit $u \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R}$ then $\tau(i(u))=1$.

For $x \in \mathcal{P}_r$, consider the divisor function $$\sigma(x) = \sum_{y \in D(x)} \tau(y),$$
next, for $\tau(x)>e$, consider the function $$u(x) = \frac{\sigma(x)}{\tau(x) \log \log \tau(x)},$$
and finally consider the sequence  $$v_n = \sup_{\tau(x)>n} u(x).$$
**Question 2**:   Is $v_n$ finite?

---

Assume that Question 2 admits a positive answer (otherwise the definition of $u$ should be modified using a more appropriate asymptotic). Then a degree $r$ cyclotomic Riemann hypothesis (CRH$_r$) can be stated as follows:

> The decreasing sequence $v_n$ (defined above with $\mathcal{P}_r$)
> reaches its limit.

Note that for $r=1,2,3,4,6$, (CRH$_r$) is obviously (RH) because then $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Z} $.

**Question 3.1**: Is (CRH$_r$) equivalent to (RH) for all $r$?
**Question 3.2**: Is there $r$ such that (CRH$_r$) is false?

---

Note that we can get alternative versions of the post replacing $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] $ by any [Noetherian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring) subring of the algebraic integers.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the cyclotomic units are dense in $\mathbb R$ for all $r$ a prime larger than $5$, and hence $D(x)$ is going to be very much infinite. This should follow from Dirichlet Unit Theorem and the classical fact that all units are a root of unity times a real number.

Comment: @Wojowu: I just did some modifications according to your comment. Now Q1 asks whether the quotient by the unit group makes the divisor set finite. Next to define the divisor function, and I introduced a natural representative for each quotient class.

Comment: You are (essentially) looking at the ring of integers of the maximal real subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_r)^+$ of the cyclotomic field. There are only finitely many ideals dividing a given nonzero ideal.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault What (or where) is the proof of that? A chain of dividing ideals (from a nonzero one) is finite because the ring is Noetherian, but how to prove that a nonzero ideal has only finitely many minimal dividing ideals?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux This is true because of uniqueness of factorisation into prime ideals. More generally, this holds in Dedekind rings.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: Thanks!  I improved the post according to your comments. I realize that historically the notion of Dedeking ring was specifically created to study the cyclotomic ring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r]$, which is [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) for $1 \le r \le 22$ but *not* in general (in particular $r=23$).

Comment: Your definition of $\tau$ is extraordinarily complicated. Furthermore, if it is not stable under multiplication by units, then your divisor function sum is not well-defined. Is there a reason to not just use the norm?

Comment: @WillSawin: No specific reason, this is what came in my mind when I wanted to define a non-negative representative. But I am not number theorist and I am open to improvement. What is the definition of the norm on $\mathcal{P}_r$?

Comment: @WillSawin: Got it, you certainly mean the [absolute norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_norm#Absolute_norm) after identifying $\mathcal{P}_r$ with the set of principal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r] \cap \mathbb{R}$. This norm maps to $\mathbb{N}$, so does not provide a representative of an element of $\mathcal{P}_r$ (seen as an equivalence class), but seems easier to deal with. Then the mean question is whether the cyclotomic RH defined in this post is equivalent to the extended RH for the corresponding Dedekind zeta function (i.e. does Robin's theorem extended to ERH?).

Comment: (1) No map that provides a representative can possibly be invariant under multiplication by a unit (easy to check) so certainly that is not a good idea. (2) Yes, I think it's almost certain that it is equivalent to the RH for the appropriate Dedekind zeta function - just go through the same proof.

Comment: @WillSawin:This post only deals with the principal ideals, whereas the Dedekind zeta function is a sum over all the nonzero (possibly non-principal) ideals. So perhaps it is equivalent to an ERH for the principal part of the Dedekind zeta function. I don't know if such a "principal" ERH is possibly inequivalent to ERH, or if it is even relevant.

Comment: You would probably count principal divisors using characters of the ideal class group. The contribution of the trivial character would dominate. If not, it's possibly the RH for Hecke L-functions associated to characters of the ideal class group would come into play.

Comment: @WillSawin: I disagree with your sentence stating that $\tau$ (as defined in the post) is not invariant by multiplication by a unit (and then that no invariant representative map exists), because an element of $x \in \mathcal{P}_r$ is precisely an equivalence class of the form  $x = a \mathcal{O}$ with $\mathcal{O}$ the group of units, so $x$ itself is already invariant by mutliplication by units: $\forall u \in \mathcal{O}$, $ux = ua\mathcal{O} = au\mathcal{O} = a \mathcal{O} = x$.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood what you meant by representative. Your map is well-defined, but I believe the expected asymptotic will be different as soon as the degree is bigger than $1$ (so $n$ not $1,2,3,4,6$.) This is because your quantity is essentially a small power of the norm. You'll get something like $e^{ log n^{ 1-1/d} / \log \log n}$ if I did the math right, where $d$ is the degree. It may not be as sensitive to the Riemann hypothesis in this case.