# On a revised quantum Riemann hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, riemann-hypothesis, subfactors, planar-algebras

This post provides a revision of the disproved quantum Riemann hypothesis proposed 2 years ago in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308300/34538), where you can refer to have more details about the motivations, the notations and the justification of the term *quantum*.

Let first recall that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sigma$ the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), and $\gamma$ the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), then $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n} = e^{\gamma}.$$
Next [Robin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin%27s_theorem) states that the Riemann hypothesis is true if and only if for $n$ large enough $$\sigma(n) < e^\gamma n \log \log n.$$

Let $\mathfrak{F}$ be the set of irreducible finite index subfactor [planar algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_algebra#Subfactor_planar_algebra) (up to equivalence), and let $\mathfrak{F}_r$ be those of depth $r \ge 2$.

Some reminders:

- [Watatani's theorem](https://doi.org/10.1006/jfan.1996.0110) states that for $\mathcal{P} \in \mathfrak{F}$, its [biprojection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_algebra#Fourier_transform_and_biprojections) lattice $[e_1, id]$ is finite.
- The index of a biprojection $b$ is noted $|b : e_1|$, and $|id:e_1|$ is the index of $\mathcal{P}$, also noted $|\mathcal{P}|$.
- The index is multiplicative, i.e. for $b,b'$ biprojections then $$b \le b' \Rightarrow |b':e_1| = |b':b| \cdot |b:e_1|.$$
- The index $|b:e_1|$ is a cyclotomic integer, and restricted by Jones index theorem.

Consider the *divisor set*
$$D(\mathcal{P}) = \{ |b : e_1| \ \text{ with } \  b \in [e_1,id] \},$$
which then is a finite subset of the (generically infinite) number theoretic divisor set $D(|\mathcal{P}|)$ in the ring of cyclotomic integers (of appropriate degree), see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/364116/34538).

Consider the *divisor function*
$$\sigma(\mathcal{P}) = \sum_{d \in D(\mathcal{P})} d.$$

**Question 1:** Is there a (finite) constant $\gamma_r$ such that the following equality holds?
$$\limsup_{\mathcal{P} \in \mathfrak{F}_r, \\ |\mathcal{P}| \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(\mathcal{P})}{|\mathcal{P}| \log \log |\mathcal{P}|} = e^{\gamma_r}$$

Note that $\gamma_2 = \gamma$ because the index of a biprojection of $\mathcal{P} \in \mathfrak{F}_2$ is a rational integer, and for $G$ a finite group (in particular $C_n$), the subfactor planar algebras $\mathcal{P}(G)$ is in $\mathfrak{F}_2$, and there is a 1-1 (Galois) correspondance between $H\le G$ and the biprojection of $\mathcal{P}(G)$, whose indices are precisely given by $|H|$.

FYI, $\mathfrak{F}_2$ contains exactly the finite dimensional Hopf C*-algebra subfactor planar algebras.

---

Assume that Question 1 admits a positive answer (otherwise the asymptotic should be improved), we can then formulate a (revised) depth $r$ quantum Riemann hypothesis (QRH$_r$) as follows:

> (**QRH$_r$**) For $\mathcal{P} \in \mathfrak{F}_r$ and $|\mathcal{P}|$
> large enough then $\sigma(\mathcal{P}) < e^{\gamma_r} |\mathcal{P}| \log \log |\mathcal{P}|$.

Note that QRH$_2$ is (obviously) equivalent to RH.

**Question 2**: What is about QRH$_r$ when $r>2$?

We can provide a variation, replacing $\mathfrak{F}_r$ by the set of $\mathcal{P} \in \mathfrak{F}$ for which the indices of the biprojections are in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r]$ with $\zeta_r = e^{2\pi i/r}$ and $r$ minimal. Let us call this variation QRH$^r$. If relevant, we can combine both variation as QRH$_{r'}^{r}$.

---

Note that it would be inappropriate to replace $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$ by  $$\tilde{\sigma}(\mathcal{P})=\sum_{b \in [e_1,id]} |b :e_1|,$$
because then above asymptotic would be incorrect, but mostly because there would be no more relation with RH, because if $\mathcal{P}_G$ is the group subfactor planar algebra for the finite group $G$ then $|\mathcal{P}_G| = |G|$ and $\tilde{\sigma}(\mathcal{P}_G)$ is the sum of the order of the subgroups of $G$ (let us call it $\tilde{\sigma}(G)$), which *explodes* for the abelian $p$-groups as $G = C_2^n$:

$$ \begin{array}{c|c} n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \newline \hline 
|C_2^n|&2&4&8&16&32&64&128 \newline \hline
\tilde{\sigma}(C_2^n)&3&11&51&307&2451&26387&387987 \end{array} $$

---

To learn more, you can watch the series [Quantum Symmetries and Quantum Arithmetic](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjudt2gd3iAf5RHw_tnYezCFXbmfNjuUJ).
The last video finishes on QRH.